# In the table i need to store the values of the Id which is selected but not able to do that Any Leads

Tags: java, selenium

Scenario:

I select Two Ids and gets added in the Table which can been seen in the below screen shot.
Over Here i need to Store the value in a Method and then call that method in other Place.
The Problem is iam not able to get the Values .

Code:

```
    public boolean checkselectedDemandId()

  
    {
        String cDemand = "";     

    cDemand = "//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]";
        
        

   List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(cDemand));` 
      for(WebElement row:rows)`

   

    {if(cDemand.length()>0)
     {  

     selectedDemandId = cDemand;     
               

     return true;
    }`else
    {
    return false;
    }
    
     public String  getselectedCreatedDemandId()
    {
    return selectedDemandId;
    }
```

HTML of the Table:

4384SELTESTTECHMTESSINGAPOREHONGKONG2030-04-092040-06-152055-12-30delete 4383SELTESTTECHMTESSINGAPOREHONGKONG2030-04-092040-06-152055-12-30delete

Comment: you need to call get Text method.  String pageText = driver.findElement(by).getText();

Comment: i tried like what you said but still not able to fetch the id  is there something else iam missing - @Jayanth Bala

Comment: please paste the html, is your xpath is correctly pointing ?

Comment: @Jayanth Bala - Xpath is correct and have already added the full html but it is not showing

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure about number of rows, use the following code

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]"));
String rowOne = rows.get(0).getText();
String rowTwo = rows.get(1).getText();
```

Comment: and my next question is how to assign the rowOne and rowTwo to selectedDemandId since iam getting the id in the next method which i use it to call it in another method - any inputs on this pls  - @Jayanth Bala

Comment: declare rowOne and rowTwo in globally.

Comment: Added like how you have given but the point where iam stuck is how to assign those values to selectedDemandIds -@Jayanth Bala

Comment: public boolean checkselectedDemandId()
 {
  String rowOne;
  String rowTwo;
  
  String cDemand = "";  
  {
  cDemand = "//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]";
   List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(cDemand));
   rowOne = rows.get(0).getText();
   rowTwo = rows.get(1).getText();
     if(cDemand.length()>0)  -

Comment: Added as per what you have said but  my only problem is how to assign these to selectedDemandId  variable - @Jayanth Bala

Comment: Can someone else give me the inputs on this

Comment: jayanthbala1993@gmail.com => please ping me the screenshot in hangout. i dont understand, what you are asking\

Comment: @ 
Jayanth Bala  - have sent a mail and also a invite.pls accept the invite